# Using Manipulate to show the solution of an ODE by NDSolve and DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, manipulate

I can't spot the error, can someone help me?

```
NumericalGenSol = 
   NDSolve[
    {g/l* Sin[θ[t]] + (γ* θ'[t])/m + θ''[t] == f/(m l), θ[0] == α Degree, θ'[0] == β Degree},
    θ[t], {t, 0, 10}];
```

`AnalyticalGenSol` is just alike `NumericalGenSol` just without `Sin` but only with $\theta$ and I used `DSolve` instead.

```
Manipulate[{NumericalGenSol, AnalyticalGenSol}, θ[t], {t, 0, 10}];
Plot[
 {Evaluate[θ[t] /. NumericalGenSol], θ[t] /. AnalyticalGenSol}], 
 {t, 0, 10}, {α, 0, 90}, {β, 0, 90}
]
```

Any idea how I can combine in one manipulate plot?

Comment: In your first codeline `NumericalGenSol = ...` there are several undefined parameters. That's why `NDSolve` doesn't evaluate!

Comment: Sorry they are defined in the top?
the error message is:
Manipulate::vsform: Manipulate argument \[Theta][t] does not have the correct form for a variable specification.

Comment: Where to find the "top"? NDSolve only works for numerical problems.

Comment: Ulrich means that you should include in your post **all definitions** necessary to run your code, otherwise we cannot run it on our machine and tinker with it to try and provide a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you define all the parameters and remove the excesses, the code can be like this

```
g = 9.8; l = 1; m = 1; f = 1; γ = .1;
sol = 
 ParametricNDSolveValue[
   {g/l*Sin[θ[t]] + (γ*θ'[t])/m + θ''[t] ==f/(m l), 
    θ[0] == α , θ'[0] == β}, θ[t], {t, 0, 10}, {α, β}];

Manipulate[
  Plot[
    {sol[α, β], 
     Evaluate[θ[t] /. 
       DSolve[
         {g/l*θ[t] + (γ*θ'[t])/m + θ''[t] == f/(m l), 
          θ[0] == α, θ'[0] == β}, 
         θ, {t, 0, 10}]]}, 
    {t, 0, 10}], 
  {α, 0, Pi/2},
  {β, 0, Pi/2}]
```

[image: fig1]